# Discarding changes with a DataGridView BindingSource to EF

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, bindingsource

I have a little problem with my windows form app.
Two forms: Parent Form - here I have DataGridView which presents list of Company. From here, I can open another form, CompanyForm, where you can add or edit selected Company. Add options work fine but when I edit company and want to discard changes, on Parent Form selected row was changed although I don't save change on my context. Someone can help me?

ParentForm:

```
private void CompaniesForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (var connect = new ContactEntities())
        {
            companyBindingSource.DataSource = connect.Companies.ToList();
        }
    }
```

Button Edit company:

```
private void buttonEditCompany_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CompanyForm company = new CompanyForm();
        company.MdiParent = this.MdiParent;
        company.Company = (Company)companyBindingSource.Current;
        company.Show();
    }
```

CompanyForm:

```
public Company Company { get; set; }    
private void CompanyForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (var connect = new ContactEntities())
            { 
                companyBindingSource.DataSource = Company;
            }
        }
```

As you can see, I use bindingsource and I don't know why grid it was automatically updates.

Comment: when you want to discard changes, try `yourGridView.CancelEdit();`

Comment: Thanks for answer.
To buttonEditCompany_Click I added companyDataGridView.CancelEdit(); but doesn't work. After changes...example name of company and press Cancel button - grid has been updated.

Comment: Usnig/Not using binding source, will not change the nature of reference types. Take a look at the [linked post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38187441/3110834).

Comment: Thanks for answer. I try to do this by re-loading the data from database to bindingsource but i don't know whether this is a good way...Someone Can help me?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Answered the wrong question. Thanks @Reza Aghaei for pointing that out to me.

Just a guess, but if you're using `Mode=TwoWay` in your binding,  try setting `UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit` and call `UpdateSource()` when you save the changes.

Comment: The question is about Windows Forms.

Comment: Oops, edited my answer to note that. Brain was stuck in WPF mode.