# Databinding to object - How to cancel datasource changes

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-binding, bindingsource

Here is the scenario:
I have an Edit Dialog form with a `BindingSource` and some data bound text boxes on it:

[image: Edit Dialogue form]

I pass an entity to the form constructor and it gets loaded into `BindingSource.DataSource` which causes the data bound controls to show the values of properties.

The problem is as the user edits the values in `TextBox` controls and `Validating` events get passed, the data source gets changed though it is not applying to DB but it still can confuses the user as he sees the edited values on the List Form, till next application restart.

so the question is: *How to prevent binding source from reflecting changes instantly or how to roll them back?*

I inherited the binding source and created a new binding source like this:

```
public class SuperBindingSource:BindingSource
{
    #region Properties

    public object DataSourceBeforeChange { get; private set; }

    #endregion

    #region Methods

    public void ResetChanges()
    {
        this.DataSource = this.DataSourceBeforeChange;
    }

    #endregion

    protected override void OnDataSourceChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnDataSourceChanged(e);

        DataSourceBeforeChange=this.DataSource.DeepClone();
    }
}
```

Though I am not sure if it is a good approach.

Comment: DeepClone() is coming from DeepCloner Nuget package which creates a clone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an option, when setting up data-bindings, you can set them to update data source never.

Then at the point that you want to apply changes, for example when pressing `OK` button, you can set data-bindings to update data source on property change and then call end edit method of the binding source.

For `Cancel` button, you don't need to do anything, because the data source is not updated.

**Example**

In form load event:

```
this.BindingContext[bindingSource].Bindings.Cast<Binding>().ToList()
    .ForEach(b=>b.DataSourceUpdateMode= DataSourceUpdateMode.Never);
```

When pressing OK:

```
this.BindingContext[productBindingSource].Bindings.Cast<Binding>().ToList()
    .ForEach(b => b.DataSourceUpdateMode = DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
productBindingSource.EndEdit();
```

You can download/clone the full source code:

- [r-aghaei/SuspendDataBindingExample](https://github.com/r-aghaei/SuspendDataBindingExample)

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer. Well isn't there a cleaner way to do it? The thing is if I wanna do it, it would be better if I go manual approch and set controls one by one. like :txtname.text=myObject.name etc. Actually I am looking for a cleaner approach.

Comment: You don't need to do anything manually. You will use data-binding to show data in controls, but the updates will not be written back to data-source until you press OK button.

Comment: In fact, with the new update which I added to the answer, you just need to add those code to form load event and click event of the OK button, without any change in your existing code. Just use a standard `BindingSource`.

Comment: Thank u so much. I marked Your answer as correct. I have a final question. Which approach is cleaner in your idea? mine or yours?

Comment: Just one point about your solution, `this.DataSource = this.DataSourceBeforeChange`, it seems it has a pitfall. The entity which you are editing is a `Class` and classes are reference type, so resetting `this.DataSource` to a new instance of object doesn't mean you reset changes. The instance is edited. You just decided to put another instance in data source. Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38187441/3110834).

Comment: In a similar situation, I used this approach: My object was serializable and it was able to Clone itself or load values from a Clone to reset itself. It was successful. Just for your information we were working with entities in a disconnected and EF was not tracking changes. It's hard to say which one is cleaner. But if I can put some effort to test the new approach, I'll definitely prefer it.

Comment: If you are going to save changes to database, in Save button, you need to use the clone approach and at the first step put the close as data source. If you are just using the form for editing an entity of a list form and later in the list form you are going to save data to database, then I'll use my approach.

Comment: I changed the solution a bit. Here you can find the whole solution to download r clone: https://github.com/r-aghaei/SuspendDataBindingExample

Comment: well this=> this.DataSource = this.DataSourceBeforeChange works for me cause this.DataSourceBeforeChange is result of a cloned object which changes my scenario into a ByVal thing.  about the EF u mentioned, yes my problem is exactly the same. After reading your approach we decided to use your code in a Form and inherite other forms from that. Thanks anyway. it solved my problem.

Comment: I am so sorry. I forgot to click the check-mark. I just up voted the answer. Fixed anyway. Again I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`SuspendBinding`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.suspendbinding%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method after the values are loaded.
After that the values should not update the source until you call `ResumeBinding`:

> SuspendBinding and ResumeBinding are two methods that allow the temporary suspension and resumption of data binding in a simple-binding scenario. You would typically suspend data binding if the user must be allowed to make several edits to data fields before validation occurs. For example, if one field must be changed in accordance with a second, but where validating the first field would cause the second field to be in error.

According to the documentation you should be able to use this with your textboxes. If the user clicks `Ok` to save the values you resume the binding and if he cancels you don't.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I used SuspendBinding but it clears the loaded values from textboxes. Am i using it in a wrong way?

Comment: @SaboueiAlireza Are you sure it "clears the values" and you are not simply calling the suspend to early? Because the method should not clear any values according to the documentation...

Comment: I put a button on the form which calls the Suspend method. The form loads the data perfectly but as soon as I press the button, it clears all the textboxes.